# Showing a certain subspace of Hilbert space is dense

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let H be the Hilbert space of square-summable sequences of reals.

A few years ago I thought I had proved that the subspace Z of real sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms, such that **they sum to zero**, is dense in H.

(Since then I've seen this confirmed in Rudin's text, Functional Analysis, 2nd ed., but only as a teensy subquestion in a terminally hairy exercise.)

Now I can't quite reproduce my proof, so it may have been wrong. Can someone please tell me how to prove that.

(What I tried was taking an arbitrary point **c** = (c<sub>1</sub>,...,c<sub>k</sub>,...) of H, and defining the point **d**(N) in H as follows for N $\ge$ 1:

First set A<sub>N</sub> = (c<sub>1</sub>+...+c<sub>N</sub>) / N. Then set **d**(N)<sub>k</sub> =  c<sub>k</sub> - A<sub>N</sub> for k $\le$ N, and set **d**(N)<sub>k</sub> = 0 for k > N.

Clearly, the element **d**(N) of H lies in the subspace Z defined above. The squared Hilbert norm of its difference with **c** is of form N(A<sub>N</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + T(N), where T(N) is just the squared norm of the tail of **c**, and so goes to 0 as N$\to\infty$.

I'm left with the expression N(A<sub>N</sub>)<sup>2</sup>, which so far I haven't been able to prove $\to$ 0 as N$\to\infty$.  I suspect this is true, and it works on all the examples I've tried so far.)

NOTE: I'm only interested in a down-and-dirty proof that doesn't invoke anything but simple inequalities.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: For a not LATEX-ed question, nice typesetting!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you arrive at "The squared Hilbert metric of its difference with c is of form $(A_N)^2 / N + T(N)$"?  that is not what I see when I look at that.

Comment: Jason, I miswrote that (A_N)^2 / N.  It should have been N(A_N)^2.  (I had been working with the sum, but in this post I used the average.) Sorry about that. (Now fixed.)

Answer (score 2):

Given $x \in H$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is $y \in H$ with $\|x - y\| < \epsilon/2$ such that only finitely many elements of $y$ are nonzero.  Suppose the sum of those nonzero elements of $y$ is $s$.  Consider $z$ obtained from 
$y$ by changing $n$ of its elements from $0$ to $-s/n$.  Thus $z \in Z$,
and $\|z - y\|^2 = n (s/n)^2 = s^2/n$.  If $n$ is sufficiently large, this is
less than $(\epsilon/2)^2$.  So $\|x - z\| < \epsilon$.  We conclude that $Z$ is dense in $H$.

Comment: I believe your proof, Robert, but I got down to essentially the same expression as your s^2 / n, and could not see a proof of why this gets arbitrarily small as n -> oo.

Comment: OK, to be more specific: My expression N(A_N)^2 in the Question is the same as Robert Israel's expression s^2/n.

Comment: I think you really need to do it in two stages, as I did.  First get rid of all but finitely many nonzero elements, then shift a finite number of elements to make the sum $0$.

Comment: To continue: In terms of the components of the original element c, s^2/n  =  (the sum of the squares of c_1 through c_n) + (twice the sum of all pairwise products c_^j c_^k with indices j,k such that 1 <= j < k <= n). Therefore, since 2ab <= a^2 + b^2, we can bound s^2 above with n SUM(n), where we define SUM(n) := ((c_1)^2 + ... + (c_n)^2).  Hence we have s^2/n  <=  n SUM(n)/ n  = SUM(n).   Instead it approaches the squared norm of **c**. Maybe @RobertIsrael can elaborate on why his s^2/n approaches 0 as n -> oo. –

Comment: Because my $s$ is constant.